# JAVA InputStream.toString() back to InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, tostring

I am playing with an an old and abandoned JAVA renderer called **Sunflow**.
In some of its classes one of methods saves image `InputStream` as string (`InputStream.toString()`).
Now I wonder: is there a way how to convert back that saved `InputStream.toString()` value to `InputStream`?

Comment: InputStream targetStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(initialString); Also you can check the following link, https://www.baeldung.com/convert-string-to-input-stream

Comment: `InputStream.toString()` does not convert the content of the input stream to a string, so it is impossible to reconstitute the content from such a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `InputStream` does not override `toString()`, it uses the existing base implementation from `Object`, which returns:

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The result of this method call is something like: `InputStream@<hex_hash_code>`, and you can not recover the original `InputStream` from this `String`.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right: after reviewing that Sunflow's code in question once again I ended up creating/adding my own simple new method that actually save the original InputStream as BufferedImage that I can re-use later directly. Thank you  for clarifying the thing to me!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mystr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Assuming the string is UTF-8 encoded.